# T-SQL cross server function execution -Is there a configuration in SQL server to execute functions cross servers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a function in `[MHL1P].[x].dbo.udf_Admin_GetNameByID(t3.StaffID)`

I want to execute this function from another server in a store procedure like this:

```
select [MHL1P].[x].dbo.udf_Admin_GetNameByID(StaffID)
    from  StaffIdTable
```

Is there a configuration in SQL server to execute functions cross servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)

Note that this is usually a bad idea, as certain things don't work as well on linked servers (the query optimizer doesn't have good information about statistics or indexes, for example).

Comment: Do you happen to know if executing a UDF on a linked server is still an issue in 2005 or 2008?

Comment: +1. Be sure you can afford the performance hit - you're adding serialization/deserialization, re-interpretation of the query, loss of use of precompiled execution plans, et cetera. Not a good idea for something used frequently. Replication might be a better choice, though it comes with its own set of issues.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) you may need to use OPENQUERY to call a UDF as this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319138) suggests.

I'm not sure if they fixed this in 2005 or 2008.